# the image does not appear even though the directory is correct laravel 8

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-8

i tried to put my website's logo but however it's not appears. note: i already reload many times, and change the browser.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/img/logo-brebes.png">
<title>SIADU APP</title>
```

file directory :
public->img->logo-brebes.png

[image]

Thank you if there anyone can help me with this problem, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try to reload your page? Ctrl + R or cmd + R on mac

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this,

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{asset('img/logo-brebes.png'}}">
```

Or

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{public_path('img/logo-brebes.png'}}">
```

Remember to always check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-public-path

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing it the wrong way. Try doing it this way

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{asset('img/logo-brebes.png')}}">
```

Comment: please read other answers before giving your own

Comment: @AhmedSbai I know the answer I provided has been posted here but a closing Parentheses was omitted which I added in my answer. Thanks for your observation

Comment: better was to comment :)

Comment: @AhmedSbai You're right